# clickedButtonAtIndex: not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5.1

Hi guys i have this i IBAction linked to a button:

```
- (IBAction)showCurl:(id)sender {
        alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert1 show];
```

}

and a clickedButtonIndex to auto run but somehow it doesn't load SecondViewController:

```
#pragma mark UIAlertView
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert1 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        SecondViewController *sampleView = [[SecondController alloc] init];
        [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
        [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
        }
    else{
            // Cancel prompt
        }
}
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: What is the problem? is the alert been shown? if so, is the delegate method been called?

Comment: The alert is shown but it does't switch to the SecondViewController as reflected in `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert1 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {`

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t give the alert view some button titles, there won’t be any buttons to tap on and that delegate method won’t get called.

```
- (IBAction)showCurl:(id)sender {
        alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert1 show]; 
}
```

Comment: So how do i do when user click the button, an alert pops up for loading and goes off after data has loaded?

Comment: Depends entirely on how you're loading your data, but you would present a view when you begin and dismiss it in response to a `-didFinishLoading` delegate callback or some other notification. UIAlertView is also the wrong UI component to use for this; it should be used sparingly to present the user with a choice. In general, you should avoid blocking the main UI with a modal view when loading stuff, especially on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show a button

```
 alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:**nil** otherButtonTitles:**nil**];
```

You pass nil as cancelButtonTitle AND nil as otherbuttonTitles, you should at least have one button title set.